# Is it possible to define a (member) function in header with explicit type and implement it with auto?

Tags: c++

I have a header foo.h defining a class Foo:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> GetVectorPtr(const std::map<std::string, int>& filter, float error);
    ...
}
```

Me, being a lazy developer, I would like very much to avoid typing so much and have a simpler implementation in foo.cpp:

```
auto Foo::GetVectorPtr(auto filter, auto error)
{
    // do work
}
```

Is it possible to do this? Would it be possible to have it in C++20 or other future releases?

Comment: `typedef std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> shared_vec_ptr;`, then just use it in both places. This is what `typedef` is for.

Comment: Or just use intellisense (if your using Visual Studio) to create the function definitions for you.

Comment: It seems to be only possible with trailing return type, which defeats the point: https://godbolt.org/z/YoqKK4. `using` will be your best bet.

Comment: Writing the declaration one way and the definition another way will only lead to confusion. Don’t do it.

Comment: @PeteBecker on the other hand, writing both the definition and the declaration is code duplication, which comes with it's own drawbacks, like harder refactor.

Comment: @AndreiM — so to avoid code duplication, you advocate writing the same thing in two different ways? That certainly gets rid of the duplication. <g>

Answer (score 2):

You could use either `typedef` or `using` keywords to get it done like so,

```cpp
using VectorPtr = std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>;
using FilterType = std::map<std::string, int>;
using ErrorType = float;

class Foo
{
    ...
    VectorPtr GetVectorPtr(const FilterType& filter, ErrorType error);
    ...
}
```

And in the definition,

```cpp
VectorPtr Foo::GetVectorPtr(const FilterType& filter, ErrorType error)
{
    // do work
}
```

Optionally if your using a tool like [Intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2019) or [Visual Assist](https://www.wholetomato.com/) to create the function definitions in the source (or header if needed) for you.